# How to use custom build agent in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-agent

I have created a custom build agent in Azure DevOps. I can view the agent in agent pool, but there is no option to select the agent when queuing the build.

I want to run the build using that custom build agent. So please guide me on how to configure the build pipeline to run with custom build agent.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a self-hosted (I assume you mean this by custom, right?) agent it goes to the `Default` pool.

[image]

So you need to select this pool when you run a build. You can either *set this pool as a default* for the build in the build configuration OR you can select it right before you start the build instead of the default one.

[image]

Comment: This is not true, when you install self-hosted agent you can configure which pool you want, is not must be the default.